# Grab certain words and phrases from a text file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have this block of code, and it goes through a text file, grabs it line by line and splits it up into separate words. This is all well and good, but within my text file, I have certain words and phrases that start with and end with '-', for example, '-foo-' or '-foo bar-'. Right now, they are being split up because of the code into '-foo' and 'bar-'. I understand why this is happening however.

My plan would be to grab those instances that start and end with '-' , store them into a separate list, then the user changes each of those phrases into something new, put them back into the list. How do I tell it to grab a certain phrase if it is two separate words?

```
def madLibIt(text_file):
    listOfWords = [] #creates a word list
    for eachLine in text_file: #go through eachLine, and split it into 
        #seperate words
        listOfWords.extend(eachLine.split())
 print listOfWords
```

Comment: Although I have provided an answer to your question, I believe there are some flaws in your thinking. Specifically, the `-` character is very common, using it as a delimiter could cause issues, what happens with hyphenated words? (like: merry-go-round) or when it is used as part of a sentence - like this? If you could give more information as to your use-case, what you are trying to do, maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Actually, the character I was using was the _ character, but that ended up italicizing my text, so I had to use the - instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `str.split()` without a separator splits the text by spaces, so you are not using `-` as a delimiter.

You can use [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with the pattern `(-.+?-)`:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(-.+?-)', 'This is a -string- with a -foo bar-')
print(matches) # ['-string-', '-foo bar-']
```

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression grabs exactly what you want.

```
import re

s = 'This is a string with -parts like this- and -normal- parts -as well-'

print re.findall(r'((?:-\w[\w\s]*\w-)|(?:\b\w+\b))', s)

>>> 
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', '-parts like this-', 'and', '-normal-', 'parts', '-as well-']
```

Comment: This code works, but I noticed that the code will throw out any word immediately before and after a non-alphabetic character in a large text file (For example, a/an returns only an, and the term '-plural noun-. And' throws out the noun and the word 'and' ". 

Also, this code won't nab any words with an "'s" (For example, there's would be 'split' into there and 's'. 
Sorry if my question is too simple, I'm really new to Regular expressions.

Comment: I am sorry it did not work as a copy-paste answer for you. If you would have provided more accurate data sample then I would have constructed a better regular expression. However, my answer was meant to provide a solution to the problem you were having using regular expressions, since I only had the limited information you provided to work with, this was the example I used. You have already selected a different answer, I will not re-edit mine with a better regular expression, though I am pretty sure that you can manage to make one yourself if it is your desire. Good luck.